# how to say "something will be known or seen or understood"?

Tags: clauses

> If we take into account the fact that he came here, then it will transpire **that** / it will become **that** / it will emerges **that** / it will come to know **that** / it will be realized **that** / it will turn out **that**.

Do the bold parts mean the same thing? and have I used **that** followed by them--verbs-- correctly?

Comment: The only thing that's bold is the word "that" so I can't tell what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I noticed is with:

> it will come to know that

"It"s are things and things don't go around knowing things all that often.  I wonder if you mean:

> it will come to be known that

Which means everyone will eventually know whatever it is you're about to introduce.

Also,

> it will emerges that

Should probably either be

> it will emerge that

or

> it emerges that

Not sure what you mean by **them** since you didn't use **them**.

Comment: Thank you so much NT. I have revised it. Exactly, you gave me the answer I wanted to know.

Comment: @nima you're welcome.  But please, my friends call me CandiedOrange :P

Comment: OP has offered six alternatives, wherein only three *(it will transpire that + it will be realized that + it will turn out that)* are valid. As well as the one you noticed, *it will become that* is nonsense, and *it will emerges that* should have the unmarked infinitive verb form ***emerge*** after the auxiliary ***will***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers do feel free to offer your own answer.